# In Jekyll, how can I programmatically modify permalinks for pages?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

In a Jekyll site with many pages (not blog posts), I want to tweak the permalink of each page programatically.  I tried a Generator plugin, something like:

```rb
module MySite
  class MySiteGenerator < Jekyll::Generator
    def generate(site)
      site.pages.each do |page|
        page.data['permalink'] = '/foo' + page.url
        # real world manipulation of course more complicated
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But although this would run and set the `page.data['permalink']` field, the output was still the same.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there a different way entirely of doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It can be easier to override the page class with something like this :

```
module Jekyll
  class Page
    alias orig_permalink permalink
    def permalink
      permalink    = orig_permalink
      newPermalink = "foo/#{permalink}"
    end
  end
end
```

Not tested.

Comment: Actually I was too quick there, it doesn't work. :( See example at https://github.com/skagedal/permalink_mod_test - there is an index.html page and two pages under "topic", but only the index page gets included in the generated _site.

Comment: However - if a page already has a "permalink" in its front matter, that gets included in the _site with its permalink properly modified. Demonstrated this by now added a third page to the repo.